# An app that uses both elastic search and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I am writing a classifieds website that will provide search functionality. Throughout my experience I have been relying on mySQL acting as a data storage so the developing with Elastic Search is something new for me.

I can see three options:

- Use Elastic Search as the only storage (there is doctrine ES extension) in my app and let it store everything - users, permissions, activity log, so on so forth
- Use MySQL and store only ID for the classified, and pull all the data from ES separately
- Replicating the data in both MySQL and Elastic Search

What is the approach that is usually taken?

Comment: Elasticsearch is not recommended to be your unique storage. ES is a search server.
The common approach would be use mysql as your database and using an event of doctrine like PostPersist you are able to send the data to elastisearch, this way will keep you elasticsearch synchronized with your mysql data.

Comment: @WaldemarNeto Thanks for the reply. Should I replicate the whole database or just the searchable data?

Comment: Try to aggregate and replicate only the data that will be searchable.

Comment: my suggestion would be to stick to mysql as primary storage and utilize the power of triggers to handle background jobs and maintain sync data between mysql and elastic.I would suggest not to go with elastic-mongo combinations as there is no official connector out there.

Comment: Thank you, things are much clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my suggestion would be to stick to mysql as primary storage and utilize the power of triggers to handle background jobs and maintain sync data between mysql and elastic.I would suggest not to go with elastic-mongo combinations as there is no official connector out there.

Having mysql as primary storage will also insure data backup for you, in case of any disaster happens to your clusters.
Make sure to maintain proper queue size for bulk indexing to the cluster.

or keep elastic as only primary storage if you don't have anything other than search and keep backs on S3 or file system.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Your answer makes in much more clear. I could not see the boundaries where ES ends and MySQL starts but your answer combined with @WaldemarNeto answer makes perfect sense

Answer (score -1):

ES is almost real-time storage, so you cannot replace a real-time storage engine. For production, an Elasticsearch cluster should have a minimum of 3 master-eligible nodes.

Synchronizing MySql with ES may become cumbersome at one moment.
I recommend you to give a try to MongoDB, Mongo2ES connector can automatically replicate data to ES when a change occurs in database.

In the end, you can use a mix of Mysql, MongoDB and ElasticSearch

1. Mysql for users, permissions, activity log
2. MongoDB for permanent classified rich data
3. ES for fast search of classified rich data

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can you please say what's wrong with the suggested approach?

Comment: Yes, please enlighten me!  Mongo connector is very official: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki and I'm using it in production without problems